# cron attempts to run the output of rsync?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, cron

Given a line in my crontab -e:

```
02  12 * * *   * rsync -r -t -v /Users/pnathan/ /Volumes/archive_hdd/
```

I get an email from cron which looks like this:

/bin/sh: #.emacs#: command not found

`#.emacs#` is the first file in the rsync listing when I run the command from the command line.

When I grep ps -Af for rsync, it turns out not to have spawned. I'm gathering that somehow, bash is trying to exec the output, but doesn't make sense, at least not from my reading of the man pages.

Comment: This seems a bit odd to me for another reason: In `sh`, `#` is treated as a comment delimiter, so it shouldn't be trying to run anything with a `#` before it, because it should be a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got one too many time spec fields. It should be:

```
02 12 * * * rsync -r -t -v /Users/pnathan/ /Volumes/archive_hdd/
```

Comment: I'm going to go have a durp over in the corner now.